# Forecasting using support vector regression in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, forecasting

I want to forecast the future energy consumption using support vector regression in R.I have this code but I'am not sure weather it is correct or not.

```
    `#gathering the data
data<-read.csv("C:\\2003_smd_hourly.csv",header=TRUE) #these are the values which are used to train the given model#
data
#data1<-read.csv("C:\\pr.csv",header=TRUE)#this file/ddata is used for checking the accuracy of prediction# 
#data1
#y1<-data1[,15] 
#x0<-data1[,2]  
y<-data[,15]    #sysload
x1<-data[,2]    #houroftheday
x2<-data[,13]     #drybulb temp(actualtemp)
x3<-data[,14]     #dewpnttemp
#train<-sample(744,447)
#train
library(e1071)
model<-svm(y~x1+x2+x3,data=data[1:48,],cost=2.52*10^11,epsilon=0.0150,gamma=1)
model
#pr<-data[-train,]
#pr
predict1<-predict(model,newdata=data[49:72,])
predict1
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(x1,y,col="red",pch=4)
#par(new=TRUE)
plot(x1,predict1,col="blue",pch=5) #plotting the values that have been predicted
#par(new=TRUE)
plot(x0,y1,col="black",pch=1)
error=y1-predict1
error
mae <- function(error)
{
  mean(abs(error))
}
mae(error)

error <- y1 - predict1

error
rmse <- function(error)
{
  sqrt(mean(error^2))
}
svrPredictionRMSE <- rmse(error)
svrPredictionRMSE
max(error)
min(error)

mape <- function(y1,predict1)
mape
mean(abs((y1 - predict1)/y1))*100
mape
```

`Eg:data can be found here http://pastebin.com/MUfWFCPM

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: This he code.I train the model using 48 values but I  want the model to predict only 24 values

Comment: I would advise against the current method you are using to input the data. Set up two `data.frames` where they are your training and testing/validation sets and supply only the training set initially, when you call `predict` then use the second `data.frame`. Your current method has redundant information in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newdata parameter for prediction (you newdata for test should have the same set of features as the training data). e.g., with mtcars dataset

```
library(e1071)
model<-svm(mpg~wt+disp+qsec,data=mtcars[1:24,],cost=512,epsilon=0.01)
model
predict1<-predict(model,newdata=mtcars[25:32,])
predict1 # prediction for the new 8 data points
Pontiac Firebird        Fiat X1-9    Porsche 914-2     Lotus Europa   Ford Pantera L     Ferrari Dino    Maserati Bora       Volvo 142E 
       28.514002        31.184527        23.022863        22.603601         6.228431        30.482475         6.801507        22.939945
```

Comment: I tried your code it is working fine.But it is not working well with my data.Can you correct any mistake if any the data link is as provided http://pastebin.com/MUfWFCPM

Comment: You have only 48 data points, you are training on the whole dataset. What do you want to predict? your code tries to predict on rows 49:72 that don't exist @Akash Joshi

Comment: Sir I am sorry looks like I have some conceptual gap what I wanted to ask is ,is it possible to predict unseen data for next day by training the model for 2 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict what happens in the next two days, you have to train a model to predict two days ahead. Let's pick a simple example, then I'll move to an SVR. Suppose we use a linear AR-direct forecasting model and, through some method we determined that two lags are enough. So we have this model:

y_{t+h} = alpha + phi_1 y_{t} + phi_2 y_{t-1} + e_{t+h}

The literature in economics calls this an AR-direct forecast because it directly ouputs y_{t+h}, as opposed to indirectly producing y_{t+h} by providing a recursive relationship across forecasts. Say that 'y' is the temperature in celcius degrees, so you want to forecast the temperature in two days using temperature data up until -- and including -- today. Suppose we use daily temperatures of the last month.

We know that ordinary least squares is a convergent estimator of alpha, phi_1 and phi_2, so we can form a matrix, X, containing a column of ones, one column of temperatures lagged h times and a column of temperatures lagged h + 1 times. Then, compute a linear projection of our temperature vector, y, on X like so: estimated [alpha, phi_1, phi_2] = (X'X)^-1X'Y.

Now, we have estimated parameters for the whole sample. If I want to know y_{t+h}, I need a constant (we arbitrarily picked '1' to estimate the model, so we'll use '1'), the temperature today and the temperature yesterday. Suppose h=2 here:

predicted temperate in two days = alpha + phi_1 x temperature today + phi_2 x temperature yesterday

You see, the difference between training the model and applying the model lies in a simple shift: y_{t} = alpha + phi_1 y_{t-h} + phi_2 y_{t-h-1} + e_{t} is what we fitted in the training sample. The last in-sample prediction we made using this model is the temperate today, using the temperatre 3 and 4 days ago, respectively. We also produced least square forecasts for all other observed temperatures, except the first three observations -- to forecast with this model, we need two observations plus a two day gap.

Now, with SVMs and SVRs, the point is very similar. Your predicted output is a real-valued label in the case of a regression problem. Suppose we also want to forecast the temperature, also two days in advance, using the same data and using the same regressors. Then, the input space of our SVR is defined by two vectors -- the same two lagged vectors of temperatures we used.

When we train the SVR on the whole dataset, we produce forecasts for each observations in the dataset -- again, except for the first three observations.

For e-insensitive SVR, let K() be the kernel we use, x_i is a support vector (it's one point in the y_{t}, y_{t-1} space) and n_sv is the number of support vectors:

y_{t+h} = sum_{i=1}^{n_sv} (alpha_i - alpha_i*) K(x_i, x)

Forecasting y_{t+h} is like asking what is the real-valued label of x: you input the last p (in this case, p=2) observations in the trained decision rule of the SVR and it gives you a label. If it was a support vector machine for classification, the training would result in a sperating hyperplane and you would decide on the label of any point which has coordinates in the input space by asking 'on what side of the plane is it?'... It's the exact same thing here, except you are looking for a real value.

So, programming-wise, you just need to provide a vector with the right dimension to 'predict': `predict(best_model_you_picked, newdata=appropriate_input_space_vector)`

Note that if you trained your model on the 'whole sample', but some of the variables you used are lagged variables, the model is not fitted on the last few observations of the non-lagged variables... just like the AR model estimated by OLS does not use the last h observations to forecast in-sample.